# How can I solve thymeleaf css not found error?

Tags: html, css, spring, frontend, thymeleaf

How can I  solve thymeleaf css not found error?

The bootstrap.min.css file is located in resources/templates/css/bootstrap.min.css.
The following sources were used to refer to this file.

```
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
           href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <title>Title</title>
     </style>
</head>
```

The result rendered on the server is `<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`.

If you access the address
I get an error `GET http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404`.

How can I solve this problem?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directory called `static` under `resources/templates/` and move `css` directory into it. The `css` and `js` should be in a directory called `static` so that the framework recognises them. The path for the css file should look as follows:

```
resources/templates/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Comment: You are a genius.

Comment: I'm glad I could help @emarwa.mouma.35t!